# Accidentally interrupted Kernal Update and now everything is broken - how to factory reset everything?

Tags: drivers

I'm unable to boot into windows - I've tried reinstalling, but I get "unexpected" errors and it kicks me out to grub.

I'm able to boot into Ubuntu, but I'm not able to connect to Wifi or Ethernet.  Ethernet says its working, but I'm not able to run `sudo apt update` or use my browser.

I installed nvidia-cuda-driver-535, and I ended up getting kicked out of ubuntu into some kind of terminal window.  It appeared to me as if the computer had frozen, since nothing was happening.  I waited a while and figured I would have to restart.

When I restarted, I couldn't use the wifi, and now everything is broken. I do not have a previous kernel version to boot to in grub.

I'd like to just factory reset everything, including the motherboard, but I'm not sure how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to reinstall I'm afraid.

Comment: @Will thats' the problem, I have reinstalled.  Both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Ah I see - sorry, I misunderstood. Are you sure your installation media is ok?